# New database refuses to show up in web2py appadmin

Tags: python, database, web2py

I am experimenting with a new blog database design and there are some tests I would like to run in web2py's administrative interface.

- I started by creating a new web2py application called `newblog` from web2py's admin interface.
- Next, I created `newblog/models/appdb.py`, below
- Then I surfed to the admin interface at `https://172.25.1.1/newblog/appadmin/index` to ensure the database was created
- I checked the filesystem and `databases/newblog.db` has a brand new creation time
- I clicked through the appadmin menu to see my new database: "web2py" > "This App" > "Database"

**Problem:** The problem is I don't see it in the database admin interface for `newblog`.  I have seen other empty web2py databases displayed in the appadmin interface, so I don't understand why mine does not show up there.

**Question:** Is this expected behavior?  If so, what are the minimal steps I need to take for my web2py database to show up in appadmin?

```
"""
newblog/models/appdb.py
"""
def build_new_table():
    return dict({'ugly_dict': 42})

db = DAL('sqlite://newblog.db')

## Build a table of tables, by the type of table (i.e. post, code, etc)
db.define_table('db_type',
    Field('name', length=32, notnull=True, unique=True,
        comment="Name of the database table"),

    #IS_IN_DB(db, 'db.%s.name' % db.db_type.name)),
    Field('database_pointer', notnull=True, unique=True,
        compute=build_new_table(),
        comment="Reference to the database table identified by 'name'",
        ),
    )

## Define tags for the database items
db.define_table('tags',
    Field('name', length=32, notnull=True, unique=True),
    )
```

Comment: "web2py" > "This App" > "Database" should take you to https://172.25.1.1/newblog/appadmin/index -- do you see the same thing in both cases? If so, what do you see? I tried your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: @Anthony, I am going to the link you mentioned.  However, I only see the default databases: `db.auth_user`, `db.auth_group`, `db.auth_membership`, `db.auth_permission`, `db.auth_event`, `db.auth_cas`; even after I hit reload on the browser. It is confusing because the database gets created.  I have tried deleting it from the file system a few times and each time it gets recreated; however, that database does not show up in the list of available db for `newblog`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you have the default `db.py` file in addition to your custom `appdb.py` file. Note, model files are executed in alphabetical order, so `db.py` is executed after your file. `db.py` assigns a different database connection to the variable `db`, so only that database is showing up in `appadmin`. You should either use the same database for both sets of tables, or use different variables for the two database connection objects. For example, in `appdb.py`, you might do:

`blogdb = DAL('sqlite:\\newblog.db')`

If you want to use the same database for all tables, then just define your DAL object in the first file (in this case, `appdb.py`), and you can refer to it in all subsequent model files (do not redefine it).